# How to get absolute file path for linked texture image?

Tags: python, export

I am writing a custom export script for blender and need to copy the textures from the materials texture slots to another location.
I am using shutil for copyfile:

```
copyfile(bpy.path.abspath(texture.image.filepath), export_path + filename)
```

This works, as long as the texture isn't linked from another .blend file. In this case, `texture.image.filepath` returns the path relative to the source blend file, not the current working file. `bpy.path.abspath` then just appends it to the current working directory, which is wrong of course. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very nice, but it's working.

```py
import os
import bpy

tex = bpy.data.images['WALL_1773.png']
# linked image from /project/assets/shaders/walls.blend

tex_path = tex.filepath
# '//../textures/walls/WALL_1773.png'

blend_dir_path = os.path.dirname(tex.library.filepath)
# '/project/assets/shaders'

full_path = blend_dir_path + tex_path[1:]
# '/project/assets/shaders/../textures/walls/WALL_1773.png'

norm_path = os.path.normpath(full_path)
# '/project/assets/textures/walls/WALL_1773.png'
```

Better code based on batFINGER's comment

```py
import os
import bpy

tex = bpy.data.images['WALL_1773.png']
# linked image from /project/assets/shaders/walls.blend

full_path = bpy.path.abspath(tex.filepath, library=tex.library)
# '/project/assets/shaders/../textures/walls/WALL_1773.png'

norm_path = os.path.normpath(full_path)
# '/project/assets/textures/walls/WALL_1773.png'
```

Comment: Certainly nice enough, since blender doesn't provide that out of the box (which i think is kind of a flaw)

Comment: I've edit my answer - there are should be `full_path = blend_dir_path + tex_path[1:]` instead of `full_path = os.path.dirname(blend_dir_path) + tex_path[1:]`. Because we use `os.path.dirname()` in the previous line (`blend_dir_path = os.path.dirname(tex.library.filepath)`)

Comment: Also check out `bpy.path.abspath(tex.filepath, library=tex.library)`  Recommend never adding path strings, use `os.path.join(...)`.

Comment: I just forgot about `os.path.join()` =)
Thanks for `bpy.path.abspath`! Edited one more time.